# Do these audio files sound natural to you?

Tags: pronunciation

I would like to know if the audio in these files sounds similar to a native speaker in terms of pronunciation. If not, please tell me why. Also, would you use audio like this to train your English pronunciation?

[Male audio](https://d1.awsstatic.com/product-marketing/Polly/voices/overview_matthew_neural.35a92b09052cbb7208ad1cd8c86bd1da894bc083.mp3)
[Female audio](https://d1.awsstatic.com/product-marketing/Polly/voices/overview_joanna_neural.3e32f17f5f6cb1b791eb261654fb260107830305.mp3)

Comment: I've closed this as opinion-based because "What do you think of...?" questions are of a [class that doesn't really fit the SE model](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask); and the two answers you have so far demonstrate that.

Comment: The quality of the audio file is low adding popping sounds and making the consonants blurred. Personally I'd listen to the BBC's World Service, on the whole English is very well articulated there and in a variety of accents from the English speaking world.

Comment: Had to go to Edge (I normally use Firefox) to get the things to play.  They sound reasonably idiomatic for American English, but a hair "stilted", and "hello" is a bit muddled at the beginning.  They would be considered very good for computer-generated speech, but the cadence is unnatural for human speech.

Comment: To me they sound heavily American.

Answer (score 1):

No, these audios sound far too accented for native English speakers. In addition, the voice doesn't sound like a natural human. The pronunciation is not English; more American.

Using computer-generated audio files to train pronunciation is extremely risky. While voice-synthesis technology and word-interpretation have improved dramatically recently, there remains the possibility that a word will be pronounced bizarrely¹. And of course, because the synthesiser is blindly following its own rules, that word will always be pronounced beautifully consistently, just consistently wrong. And you'll never know.

If you want to learn by listening — which is, after all, a vital part of childhood language development — it's far better to listen to real speakers, perhaps with the added benefit of subtitles, either in English [eg for the hard-of-hearing] or in your own language [as a translation].

---

¹ eg: one voice synthesiser I've encountered consistently pronounced *without* as /woʊ'zi:tə/ even though the fragment *withou* was rendered /wɪ'ðaʊ/.

Comment: It's difficult to say exactly why the voice is obviously mechanical, but perhaps it's just that: mechanical, too regular; too consistent; too perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these audios sound pretty natural for a native english speakers. The voice doesn't sound like a natural human, but the pronunciation of all the words sounds normal.

I think that using audio files to train your pronunciation is okay. After all, even native speakers sometimes look up the pronunciation of words and listen to audio (audio files) from the internet. However, I think it is best if you can do human to human speech to help with your pronunciation if available.